# "Grep breaks, causing the boot process to hang forever"

Tags: boot, grep

Question within a question (from the [Debian wiki](http://wiki.debian.org/DebianUnstable#Should_I_use_sid_on_my_desktop.3F)):

> Should I use sid on my desktop?
>
> If you think you can handle a broken Debian system, sure. Do you know
>   what to do if libpam0g breaks, preventing all logins? Do you know what
>   to do if grep breaks, causing the boot process to hang forever? These
>   things have happened. They will happen again.

My question is, how does a broken `grep` cause the boot process to hang forever?

Comment: One mistake I've made with `grep` is `grep -r pattern . > pattern.grep`.  Since the shell creates the output file before invoking `grep`, the `grep` command searches the output file, which grows until the disk fills up.  I have no idea whether this is related to anything that could cause the boot process to hang forever.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's common for boot scripts to call `grep` at some point. If `grep` hangs because of a bug, the first of these boot scripts that calls `grep` will hang. Or, more commonly, if one of these scripts is broken and calls `grep` without supplying a file name argument and without redirecting the input, `grep` will sit around forever waiting for console input (that's not so bad if you're in front of the console and can type `Ctrl+D`). If a script is broken and calls `grep` on a pipe or device where nobody is writing… too bad.

Answer (score 5):

Well, the obvious way would be "grep hangs forever, so something that uses grep hangs forever, and something in the boot process does that".

The text is likely to be illustrative rather than literal examples of problems, but it isn't impossible.

To really understand, start reading at `/etc/init.d/rc` and `/etc/init.d/rcS` - those are the shell scripts that run all the bits that bring up your system.